# Match everything between two strings

Tags: regex, r

Assume I have this string:

```
string <- "I2-1-EX-1-I3-1-EX-1-I2-1-I1-1-EX-1-I3-1-I2-1-EX-1-I2-1-I2-1-I1-1-I3-1-N2-1-I1-1-I1-1-I2-1-N2-1-N3-1-I1-1-NR-1-FA-1-NR-1-I3-1-I1-1-NR-1-N1-1-EX-1-QU-1-I3-1-NR-1-FA-1-EX-1-QU-1-NR-1-I2-1-I2-1-I2-1-NR-1-TR-1-I1-1-I2-1-I3-1-NR-1-I1-1-I1-1-EX-1-NR-1-NR-1-I1-1-NR-1-NR-1-I3-1-I2-1-NR-1-I1-1-QU-1-QU-1-I1-1-TR-1-QU-1-NR-1-NR-1-QU-1-TR-1-NR-1-I1-1-TR-1-I1-1-FA-1-I1-1-I2-1-QU-1-TR-1-FA-1-EX-1-QU-1-QU-1-QU-1-NR-1-QU-1-I1-1-TR-1-FA-1-QU-1-FA-1-FA-1-TR-1-FA-1-QU-1-EX-1-QU-1-I1-1-QU-1-QU-1-FA-1-FA-1-QU-1-QU-1-FA-1-FA-1-I3-1-NR-1-FA-1-I1-1-I2-1-FA-1-QU-1-FA-1-I2-1-FA-1-NR-1-I1-1-NR-1-TR-1-NR-1-EX-1-NR-1-NR-1-EX-1-TR-1-I3-1-I1-1-NR-1-NR-1-FA-1-I1-1-TR-1-EX-1-NR-1-NR-1-I1-1-I1-1-NR-1-I1-1-NR-1-EX-1-EX-1-EX-1-NR-1-NR-1-NR-1-FA-1-FA"
```

I want to match everything that occurs between two markers that contains `"I"`. For example this would mean matching, from the beginning of the string:

```
-EX-
-EX-
-EX-
-EX-
-N2-
-N2-1-N3-
-NR-1-FA-1-NR-
etc...
```

How can I achieve this match using a regular expression (ideally suitable for R)?

I have tried something along the lines of `(?=<1|2|3).*(?=I)`, but it doesn't seem to work. My rationale for the regex above is that all I's end with 1, 2, or 3 which would then be the lefthand boundary that a look-behind should find, whereas I is the righthand boundary that a lookahead should find.

Comment: i think this `I2-1-EX-1-I3` and `I1-1-EX-1-I3` also a match. But your expected output has only one `-EX-`, why?

Comment: and also i think this `I3-1-N2-1-I1` would be a match.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I think I listed that one. The principle is to match everything in between I1, I2, and I3.

Comment: It seems correct, but why is there an escaped K in there `\\K`?

Comment: but the answer you accepted has the complete different output than you expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> strsplit(string, "I\\d-\\d")
[[1]]
 [1] ""                                                   
 [2] "-EX-1-"                                             
 [3] "-EX-1-"                                             
 [4] "-"                                                  
 [5] "-EX-1-"                                             
 [6] "-"                                                  
 [7] "-EX-1-"                                             
 [8] "-"                                                  
 [9] "-"                                                  
[10] "-"                                                  
[11] "-N2-1-"                                             
[12] "-"                                                  
[13] "-"                                                  
[14] "-N2-1-N3-1-"                                        
[15] "-NR-1-FA-1-NR-1-"                                   
[16] "-"                                                  
[17] "-NR-1-N1-1-EX-1-QU-1-"                              
[18] "-NR-1-FA-1-EX-1-QU-1-NR-1-"                         
[19] "-"                                                  
[20] "-"                                                  
[21] "-NR-1-TR-1-"                                        
[22] "-"                                                  
[23] "-"                                                  
[24] "-NR-1-"                                             
[25] "-"                                                  
[26] "-EX-1-NR-1-NR-1-"                                   
[27] "-NR-1-NR-1-"                                        
[28] "-"                                                  
[29] "-NR-1-"                                             
[30] "-QU-1-QU-1-"                                        
[31] "-TR-1-QU-1-NR-1-NR-1-QU-1-TR-1-NR-1-"               
[32] "-TR-1-"                                             
[33] "-FA-1-"                                             
[34] "-"                                                  
[35] "-QU-1-TR-1-FA-1-EX-1-QU-1-QU-1-QU-1-NR-1-QU-1-"     
[36] "-TR-1-FA-1-QU-1-FA-1-FA-1-TR-1-FA-1-QU-1-EX-1-QU-1-"
[37] "-QU-1-QU-1-FA-1-FA-1-QU-1-QU-1-FA-1-FA-1-"          
[38] "-NR-1-FA-1-"                                        
[39] "-"                                                  
[40] "-FA-1-QU-1-FA-1-"                                   
[41] "-FA-1-NR-1-"                                        
[42] "-NR-1-TR-1-NR-1-EX-1-NR-1-NR-1-EX-1-TR-1-"          
[43] "-"                                                  
[44] "-NR-1-NR-1-FA-1-"                                   
[45] "-TR-1-EX-1-NR-1-NR-1-"                              
[46] "-"                                                  
[47] "-NR-1-"                                             
[48] "-NR-1-EX-1-EX-1-EX-1-NR-1-NR-1-NR-1-FA-1-FA"
```

If you wanted to restrict the digit range to 1:3 then use this pattern: `"I[1-3]-[1-3]"`

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you're trying to fetch all the characters which are in-between `I[123]-1` and `1-I[123]` . [`\K` keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html). `(?:(?!I[123]).)*?` will match any single character only if it's not a starting `I` in `I[123]`, else the match would be failed.

```
> x <- "I2-1-EX-1-I3-1-EX-1-I2-1-I1-1-EX-1-I3-1-I2-1-EX-1-I2-1-I2-1-I1-1-I3-1-N2-1-I1-1-I1-1-I2-1-N2-1-N3-1-I1-1-NR-1-FA-1-NR-1-I3-1-I1-1-NR-1-N1-1-EX-1-QU-1-I3-1-NR-1-FA-1-EX-1-QU-1-NR-1-I2-1-I2-1-I2-1-NR-1-TR-1-I1-1-I2-1-I3-1-NR-1-I1-1-I1-1-EX-1-NR-1-NR-1-I1-1-NR-1-NR-1-I3-1-I2-1-NR-1-I1-1-QU-1-QU-1-I1-1-TR-1-QU-1-NR-1-NR-1-QU-1-TR-1-NR-1-I1-1-TR-1-I1-1-FA-1-I1-1-I2-1-QU-1-TR-1-FA-1-EX-1-QU-1-QU-1-QU-1-NR-1-QU-1-I1-1-TR-1-FA-1-QU-1-FA-1-FA-1-TR-1-FA-1-QU-1-EX-1-QU-1-I1-1-QU-1-QU-1-FA-1-FA-1-QU-1-QU-1-FA-1-FA-1-I3-1-NR-1-FA-1-I1-1-I2-1-FA-1-QU-1-FA-1-I2-1-FA-1-NR-1-I1-1-NR-1-TR-1-NR-1-EX-1-NR-1-NR-1-EX-1-TR-1-I3-1-I1-1-NR-1-NR-1-FA-1-I1-1-TR-1-EX-1-NR-1-NR-1-I1-1-I1-1-NR-1-I1-1-NR-1-EX-1-EX-1-EX-1-NR-1-NR-1-NR-1-FA-1-FA"
> regmatches(x, gregexpr("I[123]-1\\K-(?:(?!I[123]).)*?-(?=1-I[123])", x , perl=TRUE))
[[1]]
 [1] "-EX-"                                             
 [2] "-EX-"                                             
 [3] "-EX-"                                             
 [4] "-EX-"                                             
 [5] "-N2-"                                             
 [6] "-N2-1-N3-"                                        
 [7] "-NR-1-FA-1-NR-"                                   
 [8] "-NR-1-N1-1-EX-1-QU-"                              
 [9] "-NR-1-FA-1-EX-1-QU-1-NR-"                         
[10] "-NR-1-TR-"                                        
[11] "-NR-"                                             
[12] "-EX-1-NR-1-NR-"                                   
[13] "-NR-1-NR-"                                        
[14] "-NR-"                                             
[15] "-QU-1-QU-"                                        
[16] "-TR-1-QU-1-NR-1-NR-1-QU-1-TR-1-NR-"               
[17] "-TR-"                                             
[18] "-FA-"                                             
[19] "-QU-1-TR-1-FA-1-EX-1-QU-1-QU-1-QU-1-NR-1-QU-"     
[20] "-TR-1-FA-1-QU-1-FA-1-FA-1-TR-1-FA-1-QU-1-EX-1-QU-"
[21] "-QU-1-QU-1-FA-1-FA-1-QU-1-QU-1-FA-1-FA-"          
[22] "-NR-1-FA-"                                        
[23] "-FA-1-QU-1-FA-"                                   
[24] "-FA-1-NR-"                                        
[25] "-NR-1-TR-1-NR-1-EX-1-NR-1-NR-1-EX-1-TR-"          
[26] "-NR-1-NR-1-FA-"                                   
[27] "-TR-1-EX-1-NR-1-NR-"                              
[28] "-NR-"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eT4wJ9/3)